# Can't show fields with null values

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

```
select * from table1  where [a]=? and [b] is null
```

When that statement is executed, it returns no records. If I change the "[b] is null" part to "[b]=?" and pass a null value to the parameter, same result: no records. BUT, if I pass a non-null value, then it works fine. I have to show the records where the b field is null.

Also, I read somewhere in this site that null doesn't match itself (null=null returns false). Why the hell is that so?

Edit: Sorry, just found this out. Was simplifying my codes for clarity.

```
select * from table1  where [a]=? and [b] is null and [c]=?
```

It only doesn't work when the "is null" is followed by another condition. How do I workaround this?

Edit 2: I made it work by rearranging the conditions so the '[b] is null' is at the end of the statement. But can someone explain this to me? Why does the statement not working properly if the "[b] is null" is followed by "and [c]=?"?

Comment: Definitively IS NULL works as expected. What is the datatype of [b]? If it is string then the answer below could be right.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be sure that the contents of column [b] in the rows you are looking to capture does actually contain NULL values? It sounds like they may be empty as opposed to NULL.

Running the query below would work if that is the case.

```
select * from table1  where [a]=? and [b] =''
```